# How to use Concat in arm template with arm template deployment task

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy different environments with arm template deployment task in devops pipeline. The concat statement is not resolved, and the servername will get the name [concat(parameters'environmentName'), 'crm001sqlsrv')] instead of testcrm001sqlsrv. How do I get concat to resolve?

```
{
    "parameters": {
        "environmentName": {
            "value": "test"
        },
        "serverName": {
            "value": "[concat(parameters'environmentName'), 'crm001sqlsrv')]"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

proper syntax for functions in the arm templates is:

```
"[function(arg1, arg2, arg3)]"
```

I'm not sure parameters support all the functions (they do support some of the functions for sure), but you can always use variable(s) to calculate the final value and use variable(s) in the template